# Help understand the error in a function I defined in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and just learnt to write simple functions. Can someone help me understand why the following function does not work.

```
fboxplot <- function(mydataframe, varx, vary)
  {
    p <- ggplot(data=mydataframe, aes(x=varx, y=vary))
    p + geom_boxplot()
  }

col1 = factor(rep(1:3, 3))
col2 = rnorm(9)
col3 = c(rep(10,5), rep(20,4))
df = data.frame(col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3)
```

Now, if I call the fboxplot function

```
fboxplot(df, col1, col2)
```

I get the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object varx not found`. I also tried

```
fboxplot(df, varx = col1, vary = col2)
```

That gives the same error. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `aes` function in ggplot2 uses names like `library()` does, i.e. it takes the name of the argument as the argument. If this is an object, it does not evaluate it but takes the name instead. Here it takes `varx` as the argument and not what `varx` evaluates too.

It works if you use `aes_string()` instead and use characters as arguments in the `fboxplot()` call:

```
fboxplot <- function(mydataframe, varx, vary)
  {
    p <- ggplot(data=mydataframe, aes_string(x=varx, y=vary))
    p + geom_boxplot()
  }

col1 = factor(rep(1:3, 3))
col2 = rnorm(9)
col3 = c(rep(10,5), rep(20,4))
df = data.frame(col1 = col1, col2 = col2, col3 = col3)

fboxplot(df, "col1", "col2")
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are passing through `varx` and `vary` vectors, while the `aes` function expects variable names (not as strings, though). One way to fix this is to use the `aes_string` function to which you can pass variable names as strings (still not vectors, though):

The following should work:

```
fboxplot2 <- function(mydataframe, varx, vary)   {
     p <- ggplot(data=mydataframe, aes_string(x=varx, y=vary))
     p + geom_boxplot()   }

fboxplot2(df, "col1", "col2")
```

Comment: @Sacha, maybe admins will have to install photo-finish cameras? :)